# enable button when certain textboxes has information

Tags: c#, winforms, event-handling, textchanged

This question has been asked but not to this extend

I have 8 textboxes, and a button which is disabled on form_load.. 4 of the 8 textboxes are required to be filled before the button can be enabled...

How do I check  that textBox1,textBox2,textBox3,textBox4 has values (excluding textBox 5 to textBox8) before enabling the button

Comment: Just use TextChanged Events on your textboxes to check if all 4 contain text and if this is the case, enable your button

Answer (score 0):

Wire `TextChanged` event for all four textboxes to a single method that checks if all of the four textboxes have some text, and then enable the button.